# How to manage a multi-technology project (Python, Javascript, Asp.net core)?

Tags: python, node.js, asp.net-core, configuration, build-system

I work on a cross-platform project which uses multiple language and technologies, including **Python** (for advanced mathematical computation), **nodeJS** (for SSR ), and **Asp.net core** for front layer (*AAA and reverse proxy). Just like every software project it needs to have some major commands to manage packages, running devtools and build the production. There are some specific mature build tools for each of them, such as, webpack and `npm` scripts for nodejs, `pip` and relevant tools like virtual environment for Python and `nuget-cli` and `dontnet-cli` for .net core partial project. Despite, In order to integrate all these tools into one build system, we need to have a sophisticated method that covers all project requirements. We have tried some of these methods, but each one has its own deficiencies when faces other projects. For example OS script files (sh and bat) files, Python script file that calls `npm` and 'dotnet' commands using `os.system()` and pure JavaScript as task runner.
The question is whether there is any better way based on your experience to have a build a development system?

- AAA = Authentication, Authorization and Accounting

#### Project structure is like this:

```
─ scripts
      |
      ├─ configure.sh
      ├─ install.sh
      ├─ ... other build scripts
─ server
      │
      ├─ nodeserver
      │     │
      │     ├─node_modules
      │     └─ ... JavaScript files
      ├─ pyserver
      │     │
      │     ├─ venv
      │     └─ ... Python files
      │
      └─ coreserver
            │
            └─ .net core solution files
```

Comment: [You can use docker containers](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container)

Comment: Each app can be in a container and can communicate with each other by for example a REST API

Comment: @mathon According to the text the question is about build system, including install packages dev and pack the production. We don't have problem with runtime, data wiring or services

Comment: So you mean like CI/CD tools like circleCI, gitlabCI or Jenkins?

Comment: With docker you can just build images of each app and push them to you test/prod environments

Comment: @mathon something like CI/CD but not like gitlabCI, mostly like gulp.